# A python code file which can't find any files I write in it

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am currently trying to make a code file that opens the files and searches the lines with inserted keywords, same kind of thing happened yesterday either. The problem is whatever I try the code doesn't find the .txt file at all. At least yesterday it had found the .txt file on my 4th try.

```
> ffile=input('ENTER THE FILE''S NAME...:')
fhand=open(ffile)
sayiLine=0
uzunluk=fhand.read()
for line in fhand:
    sayiLine=sayiLine+1
    line=line.rstrip()
    if not line.starswith('A'):
        continue
    c=input('Dosyanda :', sayiLine,'kadar satır bulunuyor.')
    d=input('Dosyanda :', uzunluk,'kadar karakter mevcut, VE BOŞLUKLAR BUNA DAHİL!!')
    f=input('Son olarak dosyanda aramış olduğun tüm satırlar şunlar:')
    print(line)
    g=input('Çıkmak için enter tuşuna basabilirsin')
```

The file I want to open is in the same folder as the code
and here is the errors I get:
[image: the error]

Sorry for the pic but the site didn't let me post the error code I am getting somehow.

Comment: Python as default uses encoding `utf-8` but it seems this file uses different encoding. You have problem with char `0x9e` and `b'\x9e'.decode('utf-8')` raise error but `b'\x9e'.decode('cp1250')` gives me `ž`. So you have to use `cp1250` when you open file

Answer (score 1):

Seems like an encoding problem, what I suggest is to change the line:

```
fhand=open(ffile)
```

to:

```
fhand = open(ffile, encoding='UTF-8')
```

or whatever the encoding of the files you are trying to open might be.

Comment: thanks for the advice but it didn't work either, I guess I'll be writing the whole code again.

Comment: @HalukCemPayım this solution can be good but you may need `encoding='cp1250'` becasue you get error with char `0x9e` and code `b'\x9e'.decode('cp1250')` gives me char `ž` (for `.decode('utf-8')` it still raises error)

Comment: @HalukCemPayım it don't matter how many times you will rewrite the code, it's clearly an encoding problem, so you should make sure that you are saving the files you trying to open and actually opening it with the same encoding.

Comment: Alright, guys thank you for the answers, I will try the things.